# Power steering seems to be coming out of its reservoir from the top. Whats wrong?

Tags: honda, accord, power-steering

I have a 2003 Honda Accord and I thought I had a leak in my power steering because of the whining noise and low fluid. I filled it back up but it kept falling out. I checked where my car is parked and couldn't find any evidence of a leek. I took it to 2 mechanics and they also couldn't seem to find the leak and just filled it up. Of course the very next day the fluid is gone again!

So just the other day I opened the hood while the car was running and noticed the fluid is coming out from the top of the reservoir.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem.  You need a replacement orange O-ring with part 91345-RDA-A01.  This video will show you the problem in great detail:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf-_qp1y4yc

BTW, if you have a V6, there is a recall on a possible leak in one of the power steering hoses.  You may want to have that checked out as well.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I recently got a mail with a recall for power steering leak on 2003 Accords. I will just have the dealership deal with it ;)

Comment: +1. I had the PS hose replaced by the dealership, then a while later the now what I know to be the "o-ring issue" crept up. Sounds like it could be both, but if it still makes noise/bubbles after its filled up AND hose replaced. I would for sure get that 1$ part, and pretty easy to DIY the o-ring replacement, espc. with one of the videos. I liked this one for the information and example of problem, but didn't bother watching his replacement technique: https://youtu.be/GR5QN3A3rJ4?t=1m38s

Answer (score 1):

The reservoir could be cracked, or cap leaking. Not sure how to check this, but if you know anyone else with a similar vehicle you can compare caps.

Comment: Nice thanks, I'll give it a shot. Luckily Accords are all over the place!

Comment: I don't think this is it, I checked the caps and they're fine. It also doesn't explain why the whine comes in and out while the reservoir is full.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Accords, but my wife has a BMW 330i and it has the same feature.  It's leaking from a vent hole in the reservoir and apparently that's "works as designed".

BMW community has accepted that the proper solution is [The Sock Mod](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1pzRJMwRx0).  Could be same vent design on honda, but not sure since don't own one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what you have is a bad o-ring on the suction side of the pump. This allows the pump to suck air when the engine is on. Honda has a updated o-ring for about $1.00 this is easy to change and will keep the reservoir from foaming up and spewing p/s fluid out from the cap.

Answer (score 1):

takes time you have to slowly turn the wheels one time in both directions with the motor running kill the motor it may work best with the cap off and let it sit 15 minutes , make sure you keep power steering full,it took me 40 times to get all the air out and not foaming ,i just got mine done today 1-19-17 , after being at the shop 3 weeks

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying it is coming out the top of the reservoir, the problem is that there is air in the power steering system. When you run the engine the fluid gets pumped into the rack where any movement tries to turn it to foam, forcing the fluid out of the reservoir. It also makes noise.

Power steering systems are often hard to burp. The basic process is to put the front of the car on jack stands so the front wheels are off the ground and let the engine idle as you turn the steering wheel all the way left and right a few dozen times. The fluid level has to be kept high enough to prevent more air from being drawn in

Comment: Your Exactly Right. -Junior- and I have a power steering cooler so it takes me EVEN longer to bleed the system.

Answer (score -2):

recall issue this is best for honda to address.

Comment: Is there a recall bulletin on this? Could you link it? What exactly is the recall for and how does the OP get Honda to do this on a 14yo vehicle?